# Formatted errors.New

Tags: go, formatting

I would like to implement a version of `errors.New` that accepts the same parameters as `fmt.Sprintf` To do so I wrote the following function:

```
func NewError(format string, a ...interface{}) error {
    return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf(format, a))
}
```

However, `a` becomes a single array parameter inside `NewError()` thereby causing `Sprintf()` to fill out just a single parameter in the format string. How can I force `a` to be interpreted as a variable number of arguments?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[`fmt.Errorf`](https://godoc.org/fmt#Errorf) already does what you are trying to do. Looking at [its source](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/fmt/print.go?name=release#211), you can see what went wrong:

```
// Errorf formats according to a format specifier and returns the string
// as a value that satisfies error.
func Errorf(format string, a ...interface{}) error {
        return errors.New(Sprintf(format, a...))
}
```

Note your code is missing the `...` after `a`. From [the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters):

> #### Passing arguments to ... parameters
>
> If the final argument is assignable to a slice type `[]T`, it may be passed unchanged as the value for a `...T` parameter if the argument is followed by `...`. In this case no new slice is created.
>
> Given the slice `s` and call
>
> ```
> s := []string{"James", "Jasmine"}
> Greeting("goodbye:", s...)
> ```
>
> within `Greeting`, who will have the same value as `s` with the same underlying array.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I find it a bit odd that Errorf is included in fmt rather than errors.

Comment: It is about keeping errors package "light". "fmt" package has many dependencies. You program becomes huge / complicated, once you import "fmt".

Comment: And also to prevent circular dependencies because package `fmt` and many of its dependencies import package `errors`.

Comment: @TimCooper I added an example. Could you check whether that is useful?